# DJANGO update is_active when email_confirmed is checked

Tags: python, django, authentication

On the Django admin interface, when I check `email_confirmed` under the Profile model, is there a way for me to automatically update `is_active` under the Djangos authentication User model? Linking them together in a way. Would like the ability to be able to check both with 1 click if a user hasn't recieved their sign-up email.

##### Profile.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    unique_id = models.UUIDField(null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

##### admin.py

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'email_confirmed')
    search_fields = ('user__email',)
    readonly_fields = ('user', 'unique_id')
    fieldsets = (
        ('Details', {
            'fields': ('unique_id', 'user')
        }),
        ('Status', {
            'fields': ('email_confirmed')
        }),
        ('Timezone', {
            'fields': ('timezone')
        }),
    )
```

I have looked into using `@reciever(setting_changed)` in Profile.py, but didn't quite understand. Similarly I have looked into the following in admin.py, and trying to set `is_active` to true in there but to no avail.

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "email_confirmed":
```

Thank you in advance for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override save method for this and save user  model whenver the email is confirmed.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    unique_id = models.UUIDField(null=False, blank=False, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.email_confirmed:
           self.user.is_active=True
           self.user.save()
        super(Profile,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

I have not implemented but I think this works.